# Find the value of the constant $A$ given the particle has the wavefunction $\psi(x,t=0)=A\cos^{3}\left(\frac{\pi x}{2a}\right)$

Tags: proof-verification, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Consider a particle in an infinite square well with $$V(x)
\begin{cases}
= 0  &   −a \lt x \lt a\\
\to  \infty & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$ 
At $t = 0$, the particle has the wavefunction (defined over $−a \lt x \lt a$):
$$\psi(x,t=0)=A\cos^{3}\left(\frac{\pi x}{2a}\right)$$

Find the value of the constant $A$.

---

Using De Moivre's theorem I was able to show that $$\psi(x,t=0)=A\cos^{3}\left(\frac{\pi x}{2a}\right)=\frac{3A}{4}\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{2a}\right)+\frac{A}{4}\cos\left(\frac{3\pi x}{2a}\right)\tag{1}$$

& using the fact that $$\psi=\sum_na_n\phi_n\tag{2}$$

Using $\mathrm{(1)}$ & $\mathrm{(2)}$ I find that
$$\psi(x, t=0)=\sum_na_n\phi_n=a_1\phi_1+a_3\phi_3$$
so $a_1=\dfrac{3A}{4}$, $\,\,\phi_1=\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi x}{2a}\right)$, $\,\,a_3=\dfrac{A}{4}$, $\,\,\phi_3=\cos\left(\dfrac{3\pi x}{2a}\right)$

Now using 
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}{\lvert a_n \rvert}^2=1$$

So $$\left(\frac{3A}{4}\right)^2+\left(\frac{A}{4}\right)^2=1$$

Which, on rearranging, gives $$A=\sqrt{\frac85}$$

---

The problem is that the correct answer is $$A=\sqrt{\frac{8}{5a}}$$

I am very curious about why that factor of $a$ is part of the normalization constant $\mathrm{A}$ since it is also half the width of the well and appears in the argument of the cosine eigenstate. How can this normalization constant have a property of the system?

I have applied what I thought was the correct logic. But it seems I am missing something. Does anyone have any idea how the author reached that answer?

---

### EDIT:

I have been given two answers to this question, thank you to those that took the time to answer.

There is still one thing I can't understand, and unfortuanately I will have to upload the full question and solution in order to get the point across. Below is a 2nd year undergraduate physics assessed problem:

[image: 2nd year QM assessed]

---

Here is the professors solution to the first part of the question:

[image: 2nd year QM soln, part 1]

---

and here is the solution to the second part of the question:

[image: 2nd year QM soln, part 2]

Many thanks.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier The voltage function $V$ is a part of the differential (Schrodinger's) equation to which $\psi$ is a solution.  For more, see the [particle in a box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box) wiki page.

Comment: @BLAZE "Irrelavant to the problem" isn't quite the right way to put it, but hopefully you see what I mean. Finally, the error in your approach is that your $\phi_1$ and $\phi_3$ are not *normalized* eigenstates; they need to be scaled so that $\int \phi_j^2 dx= 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to state that you have a mistake.  The (normalized) eigenstate function $\phi_n$ should look like
$$\phi_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\,\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{2a}\right)\text{ for }x\in[-a,+a]\,.$$
This can be easily checked since
$$\int_{-a}^{+a}\,\cos^2\left(\frac{n\pi x}{2a}\right)\,\text{d}x=a\,.$$
Therefore, from (1) and (2) in your question, you should get $$a_1=\frac{3A\sqrt{a}}{4}\text{ and }a_3=\frac{A\sqrt{a}}{4}\,.$$

Comment: That's excellent! (+1) This is exactly what I was hoping to see

Comment: Could you please explain why $1/\sqrt{a}$ normalizes the eigenstates

Comment: From your study (or wherever you got this problem from), you should get that the $n$-th eigenstate $\phi_n$ satisfies $\phi_n(x)=\alpha_n \cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{2a}\right)$ for $x\in[-a,+a]$, right?  You want to normalize it, using $\int_{-a}^{+a}\,\big|\phi_n(x)\big|^2\,\text{d}x=1$.  This is where the second equation of my answer comes into play, and you then get $\alpha_n^2=\frac{1}{a}$.

Answer (score 2):

You're working far too hard.  Just normalize your wave function:

$$\int\limits_{-a}^a \left| A \cos^3 \left( {\pi x \over 2 a} \right) \right|^2 dx = A^2 \int\limits_{-a}^a \cos^6 \left( {\pi x \over 2 a}\right) dx = 1$$

where the integral is computed symbolically instantly in *Mathematica* or can be found in a table or can be computed through the trigonometric substitution given by Omnomnomnom, below.

Regardless, this method gives $A = \sqrt{{8 \over 5 a}}$ very quickly indeed.

Incidentally, indeed your (incorrect) answer *must* depend upon $a$.  Qualitatively, if $a$ is large (the normalized wave function is spread out), then its amplitude $A$ must be small.  In fact, if you think about the physics, the the amplitude must go down as $1/\sqrt{a}$.

Comment: I think you might be the one working too hard if you're going to try and do it like that.

Comment: @BLAZE:  Huh?  The integral is simple, and the answer appears immediately, avoiding all the series expansions and deMoivre's Theorem you employ.  It also gives the correct answer whereas yours does not.  Why the down-vote?

Comment: @BLAZE the usual (without series or complex analysis) method of evaluating $\int \cos^6(u)\,du$ is to use trig identities:
$$
\cos^6(u) = \frac 1{2^3}[1 + \cos(2u)]^3 = \frac 18[1 + 3 \cos(2u) + 3 \cos^2(2u) + \cos^3(2u)]
$$
the only terms above which have a non-zero integral over a period are $1$ and $3 \cos^2(2u)$.  The latter can be integrated by applying the same identity again.

Comment: @BLAZE:  I solved your entire problem, beginning to end, in less than five minutes--I'll bet less time than it took you to write out the MatJax.  (Granted, I have a PhD in physics and was a physics professor for many years.)  But the core idea of $\int | \psi(x)|^2 dx = 1$ is so basic I don't know why anyone would use a different method.  Regardless, I'll look forward to your "faster" method in 9 or so days.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I think that your answer would benefit from a quick explanation of how one should compute the integral in question, especially since this is the asker's apparent sticking point. +1 regardless.